# Getting java.sql.SQLException: XA error: XAResource.XAER_PROTO start() failed on resource error in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, datasource, xa

I am getting below exception in the application log while getting a connection from data source. Though it is showing "caused by: cannot start a new transaction" in the exception, I am not starting new transaction anywhere.

1. I am facing this issue intermittently, it does not occur every time.
2. I am using web logic 12c (weblogic version 12.1.3.0.0) & using thin/XA driver.
3. I am facing this issue only on production environment other environment doesn't have the issue.
4. Using oracle 12.1.0.2.0 as a database
5. using ojdbc6.jar (Oracle jdbc driver version 12.1.0.2.0 JDBC 4.0 )

Exception I am getting,

```
cause:java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: XA error: XAResource.XAER_PROTO start() failed on resource 'myds': XAER_PROTO : Routine was invoked in an inproper context
    oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1229)
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:246)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.start(DataSource.java:830)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.start(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1311)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.xaStart(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1244)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.enlist(XAServerResourceInfo.java:292)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:585)
        at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:490)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1749)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1651)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnectionInternal(DataSource.java:517)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:494)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnectionInternal(RmiDataSource.java:565)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:545)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:538)
    ....
    .....
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24776: cannot start a new transaction
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1018)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIOtxse.doOTXSE(T4CTTIOtxse.java:164)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource.doStart(T4CXAResource.java:188)
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:241)
        ... 60 more
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1754)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1651)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnectionInternal(DataSource.java:517)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:494)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnectionInternal(RmiDataSource.java:565)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:545)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:538)
```

We are thinking it might be incompatible JDBC driver issue, but is it right finding or we may need to check something else?

Answer (score 0):

have you configured your `db` for `xa` by running `initxa.sql` script ? If not, then use the following :
[ be careful to replicate this environment to ***another machine*** other than ***production*** ]

```
$ sqlplus / a sysdba
SQL> @?/javavm/install/initxa.sql -- this file is located at $ORACLE_HOME/javavm/install directory.
```

if you fail due to database's memory lackage, run the `initjvm.sql` script( *located at the same directory* ),

```
SQL> @?/javavm/install/initjvm.sql
```

during execution it will indicate which parameters need to be adjusted.

Probably, it might tell you to increase `java_pool_size` & `shared_pool_size`, and do so in that case.

Comment: Just to understand the execution sequence, do I need to execute initjvm.sql if I failed to execute initxa.sql  file? Right now 0 value set for java_pool_size & shared_pool_size oracle properties, do I need to set some value for these properties as well?

Comment: @RiteshChopade exactly, if you failed to execute initxa.sql run initjvm.sql. Ask your dba if your db is AMM(automatic memory management). Perhaps your db is AMM and no need to be set these params( java_pool_size & shared_pool_size) explicitly.